# React Component Wrapper Passes Props Down

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

Im building a Compoenet Wrapper in React. My Goal is to wrap any componenets that need some specific data with this wrapper that will pass this data to the compoenent when rendering it. THe only issue i am facing is pass down the other require props in of the compoent being wrapper. here is my code.

```jsx
"use client";
import { useGetMyself } from "@/client/api/user/queries/useGetMyself";
import { User } from "@/client/graphql/hooks";
import React from "react";
import { GenericFetchProblemDialog } from "../custom/dialog/GenericFetchProblemDialog";
import { env } from "@/env";

interface UserWrapperChildrenArgs {
  user: User;
}

interface UserWrapperProps<C extends UserWrapperChildrenArgs> {
  component: React.FC<C>;
  loadingComponent: React.FC;
  showErrorDialog?: boolean;
}

const UserWrapper = <C extends UserWrapperChildrenArgs>({
  component: MainComponent,
  loadingComponent: LoadingComponent,
  showErrorDialog,
  ...props
}: UserWrapperProps<C> & Omit<C, "user">) => {
  const { user, loading, notification, refetch } = useGetMyself();

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingComponent />;
  }

  if (user === null || notification) {
    return (
      <>
        <LoadingComponent />
        {showErrorDialog && (
          <GenericFetchProblemDialog
            defaultOpen={true}
            open={true}
            retry={() => {
              refetch();
            }}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }

  return <MainComponent user={user} />;
};

export { UserWrapper };
```

This is how im currently callign it.

```jsx
import { UserWrapper } from "@/components/hoc/UserWrapper";
import { BreadCrumbs } from "./BreadCrumbs";
import { NavigationStrip, NavigationStripSkeleton } from "./NavigationStrip";

export default function BodyLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div className={`h-[100vh] flex`}>
      <div
        className={`border-r-[1px] border-gray-200 flex-none w-64 shadow-md flex-col`}
      >
        <UserWrapper
          loadingComponent={NavigationStripSkeleton}
          component={NavigationStrip}
          showErrorDialog
        />
      </div>
      <div className={` w-full flex-1 px-5 flex flex-col`}>
        <BreadCrumbs />
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i want to be able to pass other props and have typescript typing for those props based on the compoent i pass to the UserWrapper.

Comment: Does the wrapper component need the props? if not, you can pass the component in as JSX: `<UserWrapper component={<NavigationStrip foo='bar' />} />`

Comment: The component wrapped must have a property of user on it, in order for it to be used by the wrapper. If I construct the Wrapped Component on the same line as the WrappingComponent I will need to provide the user object to it, which is the reason why I am building this wrapping comonent, to fetch the user and supply it to the wrapped component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution!

I switch it to a HOC function.

```
import { useGetMyself } from "@/client/api/user/queries/useGetMyself";
import { User } from "@/client/graphql/hooks";
import React from "react";
import { GenericFetchProblemDialog } from "@/components/custom/dialog/GenericFetchProblemDialog";

interface WithUserProps {
  user: User;
}

interface UserWrapperProps {
  showErrorDialog?: boolean;
  loadingComponent: React.ComponentType;
}

export function withUser<T extends WithUserProps>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>,
  args: UserWrapperProps
) {
  const { loadingComponent: LoadingComponent, showErrorDialog } = args;
  return function WithUser({ ...props }: Omit<T, keyof WithUserProps>) {
    const { user, loading, notification, refetch } = useGetMyself();

    if (loading) {
      return <LoadingComponent />;
    }

    if (user === null || notification) {
      return (
        <>
          <LoadingComponent />
          {showErrorDialog && (
            <GenericFetchProblemDialog
              defaultOpen={true}
              open={true}
              retry={() => {
                refetch();
              }}
            />
          )}
        </>
      );
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...(props as T)} user={user} />;
  };
}
```

I take no credit for this solution. Check this link for more information:- https://stevekinney.github.io/react-and-typescript/higher-order-components

It makes sense!